# How to search for an item and select that item within a dropdown HTML(rails)?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a dropdown menu for a form where the user selects an item. So far, I have only been able to get this work using links like `<a href=...` but cannot seem to have the user select an item to submit in the form. How to swap out the links for this? Below is a snippet of code.

**FYI this should be an input where the user selects an item from the dropdown menu (has search capabilities). This is just one of a few questions for users to answer.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Select Item</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#item2">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#item3">Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is checkboxes because checkboxes are the options and will get submitted with the form. You can change your HTML to

```
<h2>Select Item</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <input id="item-1" name="item-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
    <input id="item-2" name="item-2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-2">Item 2</label>
    <input id="item-3" name="item-3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-3">Item 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then just change your CSS to:

```
.dropdown-content input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0.01;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/e/E/I/2/i/dark-green-check-mark-md.png');
  background-position: center right 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px auto;
}

.dropdown-content label {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown label:hover {background-color: #ddd}
```

Now there could be some tweaks in structure but that's up to you.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
}

.show {display:block;}

.dropdown-content input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0.01;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-image: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/e/E/I/2/i/dark-green-check-mark-md.png');
  background-position: center right 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px auto;
}

.dropdown-content label {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown label:hover {background-color: #ddd}
```

```html
<h2>Select Item</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <input id="item-1" name="item-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
    <input id="item-2" name="item-2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-2">Item 2</label>
    <input id="item-3" name="item-3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="item-3">Item 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for the answer. After selecting an element from the dropdown, is there a way to display it as an input or a label (maybe replace "Dropdown" with the name of the item chosen? That way the user can see what they selected without clicking through the button again.

Comment: What you want to do is listen for changes to the checkbox then change the dropdown's content when it happens: https://jsfiddle.net/4vaervkj/20/

Comment: Actually sorry I would store that somewhere else because you want to keep the input value, https://jsfiddle.net/4vaervkj/23/

Comment: I took a look at the script. What if the user wants to change their response?

Comment: What you could do is not hide the drop down then. The value could be placed anywhere you want. So you could append it to the drop down button or have a different element that display selected results.

Comment: This is a better fit for a select tag with the multiple option.

Comment: Probably not, because of the search there. The implementation wouldn’t be that much different. You could do the search directly on the options but you’d still need to put the selectable/clickable elements outside for the sake of styling. Radio buttons would probably be more appropriate for this exact use case here.

Comment: @jerrylow I've spent the past hour trying to tweak the code to allow users to change their response, but appear to have gone a full circle...

Comment: Is it possible to use `<select>` with `<option>` in this case?

Comment: @ImmaNoob it doesn't matter, but I can tell you this - having a `<select>` version will cost you more code because there's no one to one relationship from label to `<option>` so you need to create a function that generates labels from dynamically changing options then map those labels back to the options. As previously suggested you probably want to use radio buttons if the user can only select 1 option, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/4vaervkj/25/

Comment: Hi Jerry, so an update to the code- I actually now have 12 options that the user can select. I no longer think radio buttons would be the way to go

Comment: @ImmaNoob I personally don't see why the number of options is relevant, but maybe I'm missing something. I've used radio/checkboxes for large filter lists before. But if you don't think it doesn't work for you, you can swap for any other form element you want.